# UserControl not rendering children when added to a page using aspx tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I must be missing a trick here. I have an `.aspx` page (that uses a master page, if that matters) with the following code in it:

```
<me:ModuleContainer runat="server" ID="topmodules"></me:ModuleContainer>
```

Now for some reason, my UserControl for `ModuleContainer` is called, all the properties on the control are called correctly, however it seems it just doesn't fill the control with the children in the `.ascx` file. Whereever I try to access them in the code (tried on Load and PreRender), the values are always null.

But it works if I programatically add it with the `LoadControl` method (but not just by declaring a new instance of `ModuleContainer`.

Ideally I'd like to get it working when loaded in the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post some markup and code?

Comment: Yeah sure, but what do you need?

Comment: Oh bugger I've got it.. registering the control individually worked. It doesn't like the assembly+namespace markup for ascx files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not even quater of an hour after asking the question, I worked it out.

Control wasn't registered in the `web.config` file as the `.ascx` file. I was trying to register the whole namespace using this markup.

```
<add tagPrefix="me" assembly="My.Website" namespace="My.Website.Controls" />
```

But it worked fine when I used this markup

```
<add src="~/Controls/ModuleContainer.ascx" tagName="ModuleContainer" tagPrefix="me" />
```